# How to set ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json to false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, activemodel

I'm using Rails 3 w/ Mongoid, (so no ActiveRecord). Mongoid uses ActiveModel's "to_json" method, and by default that method includes the root object in the JSON (which I don't want).

I've tried putting this in an initializer:

```
ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

But get the error

```
uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Base
```

Any ideas how I can change this? I changed the default directly in the source-code and it worked fine, but obviously I'd like to do it properly.

The variable is defined at the top of this file:
[Github - activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb)

From the docs:
"The option ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json controls the top-level behavior of to_json. It is true by default."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

in an initializer??

Comment: Ah I was editing the question while you wrote this. I had tried this already, and am getting an error. Any ideas?

Comment: I've talked to more people, and confirmed that this is indeed how it should be done. I must have something else in my code messing it up.

Comment: This response is outdated. Nowadays rails complains `unitialized constsnt 'ActiveModel::Base'`

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old, but another way you can do this is by placing this within your application class in application.rb:

```
# When JSON-encoding a record, don't wrap the attributes in a hash where the
# key is named after the model
config.active_record.include_root_in_json = false
```

Comment: The easy way if you need this to apply to all your models.

Comment: he asked for ActiveModel, not ActiveRecord, thats a big difference

Answer (score 4):

You should simply set it on the class that includes the ActiveModel modules:

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  self.include_root_in_json = false

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer initializers, it's `ActiveRecord::Base`, not `ActiveModel::Base` in Rails versions 2.* and 3.1, possibly 3.0. Looked through the source, and in 3.0 beta it was switched to ActiveModel, but back again to ActiveRecord at some point.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

Also, in case you're actually trying to use this functionality, in Rails 3.1 the params wrapper is relevant:

> ActionController::ParamsWrapper
>
> Wraps the parameters hash into a nested hash. This will allow clients to submit POST requests without having to specify any root elements.

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html